# Why does zoom in small size of image in IE9 cause image distortion?

Tags: html, zooming, graphic

I am about to design a series of tabs with an 11px x 11px "X" for the close icon.

In IE9, if I zoom it to 95%, I saw a image distortion of the "X". I did a test of displaying multiples of the same icons and zoom it, it works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox but not in IE.

I think there is something to do with the custom zoom, because in Chrome and Firefox you can only zoom it by 10% each time.

Please correct me if I'm wrong about this.

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed ^^

I don't think you can solve this. You can't control how Internet Explorer resizes images during zoomchange. Because this is a problem concerning one/two pixels it's only noticable when the image is very small. Internet explorer is obviously calculating the height and the width in different manners.

Comment: Thx for your reply ^^ I know that the box model in IE is different than the W3C standard model. From outer to inner, there are margin, border, padding and content. The width of W3C standard is the content itself only. However, the way which IE measures the width is the border + padding + content. here is the link for this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug but I dont know if IE9 still behave like this.. Could this be the cause of  my bug?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you expect that an 11px x 11px image would look *good* displayed at 95% size? If you want it smaller, create a 10px x 10px version.

Answer (score 0):

IE uses a completely different rendering engine to the other browsers.

Internally, when a zoom occurs, it will re-draw the browser area with scaling applied. Some browsers use anto-aliasing and other techniques to remove or mitigate artifacts.

Unfortunately, this isn't something you have any control over.